# Filtering a group of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the SQL structure below:

```
CREATE table TestTable (id int not null identity, [type] char(1), groupid int)

INSERT INTO TestTable ([type]) values ('a',1)
INSERT INTO TestTable ([type]) values ('a',1)
INSERT INTO TestTable ([type]) values ('b',1)
INSERT INTO TestTable ([type]) values ('b',1)
INSERT INTO TestTable ([type]) values ('a',2)
INSERT INTO TestTable ([type]) values ('a',2)
```

The first four records are part of group 1 and the fifth and sixth records are part of group 2.

If there is at least one b in the group then I want the query to only return b's for that group.  If there are no b's then the query should return all records for that group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
SELECT *
FROM testtable
LEFT JOIN (SELECT distinct groupid FROM TestTable WHERE type = 'b'
) blist ON blist.groupid = testtable.groupid
WHERE (blist.groupid = testtable.groupid and type = 'b') OR
      (blist.groupid is null)
```

How it works

- join to a list of items that contain b.
- Then in where statement... if we exist in that list just take type b.  Otherwise take everything.

---

As an after-note you could be cute with the where clause like this

```
WHERE ISNULL(blist.groupid,testtable.groupid) = testtable.groupid
```

I think this is less clear -- but is often how advanced users will do it.